# Free aternative to Titanpad.com that supports programming languages

Tags: web-apps, text-editor, collaboration, programming

For those who don't know what Titanpad.com is, check it out.

TitanPad is a nice, real time, online document editing and collaboration tool that helps you quickly collaborate on text documents with your team or in my case, people I'm trying to teach. It has a chatroom where they can ask question, their edits show in different colors and so on. I'm using it to teach Java.

From [Etherpad's wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etherpad)

> Etherpad is a web-based collaborative real-time editor, allowing
>   authors to simultaneously edit a text document, and see all of the
>   participants' edits in real-time, with the ability to display each
>   author's text in their own color. There is also a chat box in the
>   sidebar to allow meta communication.

Titanpad is like Etherpad, but web based, Etherpad has to be installed on some machine.

I want something just like Ttanpad with two additional features

- Syntax highlighting for programming languages
- Auto indentation support
- Optional: ability to run the code, and see the output. Like [Ideone](https://ideone.com/)

Comment: if it belongs on web apps migrate it, but I think it belongs here.

Comment: You should explicitly state what you use titanpad for. The vague buzzword description doesn't help.

Comment: @Clearquestionwithexamples I did, although I believe that my question wasn't vague at all, anyway, Copied and pasted a wiki paragraph. I guess that I have enough rep to prove that I know the rules and didn't sign up yesterday

Comment: I understand it now. You've looked through the relateds? http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/10580/real-time-code-collaboration?rq=1 http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/146/self-hosted-collaborative-real-time-editor?rq=1

Comment: @Clearquestionwithexamples yes that one is old, i even considered answering it back then, I'm not looking for a collaboration IDE, I'm looking for a web based programming teaching platform, I'm the only teacher, user cant edit my code without my explicit permission, a chat room for users to ask their questions, and optionally, ability to run code so they can see the output, but that is optional, my main concern is teaching not the IDE, and all web based. the question you pointed to is for programmers to work together, no chatroom